# Enable SchemaStore support if filename does not match

Tags: visual-studio-code, schemastore

VS Code has support for [schemastore](https://www.schemastore.org/json/) which gives you autocomplete in YAML files.

But VS Code does not detect the schema if the filename is different.

For example, if I edit `.golangci.yaml` the corresponding schema gets used. If I edit `.golangci-foo.yaml` the schema is not detected.

How can I enable the schema for files where the filename is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `json.schemas` setting. Like so:

```json
"json.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [ "*tsconfig*.json" ],
        "url": "http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    },{
        "fileMatch": [ "*cSpell.json" ],
        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/streetsidesoftware/cspell/cspell4/cspell.schema.json",
    },{
        "fileMatch": [ "*.webmanifest" ],
        "url": "http://json.schemastore.org/web-manifest",
    },{
        "fileMatch": [ "*package*.json" ],
        "url": "https://json.schemastore.org/package",
    }
],
```

As indicated in the comments, this worked for the asker, and they used the following:

```json
"json.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [ "*.golangci*yaml" ],
        "url": "https://json.schemastore.org/golangci-lint.json",
    }
],
```